# React Native Error: Unable to resolve module [...]" "None of these files exist: * App(.native|.android.ts|. ./App App(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|"

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

I installed a npm package called country-query, when i run the app it gives this error
[image]

it installs another package/dependency world-countries, but the files in that package are not installed correctly

This is how it looks:
[image]
I have used the same package in previous project, where everything works find and there the world-countries looks like this:
[image]

This is not specific to this package, whenever i am installing a new package its dependency package is not getting installed properly, and it throws the above that saying none of the files exist.

When i paste the files of from previous project's node_modules/world-countries package to new project, it works, but whenever i install a new package, it gets reset to image 2